# USB Flash Drive is writeable but can't delete files

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have an external HDD, which can be powered by either using a Power Supply or the USB port itself. When I use the USB to connect directly to my computer, I can access the Filesystem, can *Copy Files* to my drive, I actually can edit them and *Save Files*, but I cannot *Delete*, *Create* nor *Save Files as New File* on the drive.

But if I use the cable and plugin my USB cable after 6 seconds, it suddenly works!

This problem does not appear on Windows XP, but on Windows 7 and 8.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Do you have the right drivers for your HDD compatible with Windows 7 or 8? How old is your HDD?

Comment: What file system are you using?  What is the exact model.  Sounds like the power supply isn't as optional as you might think it is.

Comment: @Firee I don't know if I have the right drivers... Do you know what changed from Windows XP to 7 when loading the USB drive?

Comment: @Ramhound I can't really tell you the exact model, because its a Device our company makes and inside of it is a Flash Drive. What really makes me wonder is the fact that only windows 7 and 8 have those problem. Windows XP works perfectly fine.. Did something change in reading a Flash drive from XP to win 7 ?

Comment: Can you please mention the details about external HDD? Model Number, Power Rating etc.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a permission problem. Usually large external USB flash devices are formatted with NTFS which supports permissions for creating, editing, reading, deleting of file/directories.

As this is unwanted on an external USB flash all files are usually created using the permission "Everybody" set to "Full control". May be because of an error or a certain application it looks like the permissions were changed.

I would do the following:

1. First I would check the disk for errors (chkdsk).
2. On Windows 7/8 open the property page of the disc and select the security tab. Edit the permissions and add "Full control" for Everybody and apply this to all files, folders and subfolders.

Alternatively if you can backup all the files from the stick, and just format it new. This should also "erase" all your problems.

Comment: I can't access any Security Tab because there is none :/

Comment: Then you are on Windows XP or the stick is FAT formatted. The latter case you have to format it and hope that it is not a hardware defect.